# How to convert a normal invoice PDF to Zugfered XRechnung format file in C#?

Tags: c#, zugferd

I am trying to convert a German invoice PDF to Zugfered format using C# ZUGFeRD-csharp (s2industries) library. Its works fine in B2B (Business to Business)  with using below line

```
ZUGFeRDVersion.Version21, s2industries.ZUGFeRD.Profile.Comfort
```

But user wants to B2G (Business to Government) XRechnung format. I just changed to below line

```
ZUGFeRDVersion.Version21, s2industries.ZUGFeRD.Profile.XRechnung
```

But getting below exception,

> Invalid Factur-X URN: 'urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017#compliant#urn:xoev-de:kosit:standard:xrechnung_2.2

Even i downloaded Zugfered 2.1.1 version, and replaced my existing schema xsd like Basic, Basic WL,en16931,extended and minimum.

Comment: I don't think this is related to C# in particular. For helping with the invalid urn the question does not contain enough information.

Comment: I have resolved that error using update the 2.1.1 schema folder. Now i can get Xrechnung xml. During Xrechnung validation getting below exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the zugfered version 2.1.1 Schema like Basic, Basic WL,en16931,extended and minimum.